# Why is this Excel IF Query Not Working?

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
=IF(ISBLANK(CM7),"",IF(CN7=F7>1,-1,  IF(CN7=F7>-1,1,  IF(CN7=F7,0))))
```

What I want to say is that if cell `CM7` is blank, then leave the cell where the calculation takes place blank. Otherwise, if `CN7 > F7`, enter `1`. If `CN7 = F7` type `0`. If `CN7 < F7` enter `-1`

Whatever I enter in `CM7` at present, it always gives the answer of `-1`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why write `CN7=F7>1` when the obvious condition is `CN7<FN7` (and the same with the "less than" condition?

Answer (score 1):

You are close. You have too many operators in your formula. You need to just tell it what to check; is `CM7` greater than `F7` would be `CM7>F7`. You don't need the equals sign (`=`) in there.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(CM7),"",IF(CM7=F7,-1,  IF(CM7>F7,1,  IF(CM7<F7,0))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You two were close, but what you gave me, enabled the problem to be resolved.

```
=IF(CM7="",CM7,IF(CN7>F7,1,IF(CN7<F7,-1,0)))
```